# how do I tell an array pointer from a regular pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I'm writing a smart pointer like std::shared_ptr since my compiler does not support c++17 and later versions, and I want to support array pointer like:

```cpp
myptr<char []>(new char[10]);
```

well, it went actually well, until I got the same problem as old-version std::shared_ptr got:

```cpp
myptr<char []>(new char);
```

yeah, it can't tell whether it's a regular pointer or an array pointer, and since my deleter is kind of like:

```cpp
deleter = [](T *p) {delete[] p;}
```

which means it just meets the same problem that the old-version std::shared_ptr has.

my array-pointer partial specialization is like:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename DeleterType>
class myptr<T[], DeleterType> { // DeleterType has a default param in main specialization
                                // as std::function<void(T*)>
private:
    my_ptr_cnt<T, DeleterType> *p; // this is the actual pointer and count maintain class
public:
    // constructor
    /// \bug here:
    my_ptr(T *p, DeleterType deleter=[](T *p) {delete []p;}) :
        p(new my_ptr_cnt<T, DeleterType>(p, deleter)) { }

}
```

Comment: A pointer is a pointer, you can't differentiate whether it points at a single item or at an array of items. So it is the responsibility of the caller to give you the correct kind of  pointer to begin with. Same as with the standard smart pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "old-version std::shared_ptr".  `std::shared_ptr<int[]> foo{new int}` will still compile just fine in C++20.  Its destructor will invoke undefined behavior, but the compiler won't stop you from stepping on that particular landmine.

Comment: @MilesBudnek thx, I didn't test it on c++20, since it's not supported on my compiler. so I just say on my "old-version"ed compiler, there would be a problem. sry if it's a confusing expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This is one of the many reasons that raw arrays are bad.

What you can do is forbid construction from raw pointer, and rely on `make_shared`-like construction.